# Combining CSS Animations. What next?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to make an animation of a stack of folders, where they will raise up, and then open to reveal the inside of the folder on hover (all but the bottom folder need to rise).

So far I have made the all top folders rise, and I've made the bottom folder open. Where I'm stuck is how to get the top folders to open after they rise. (side problem: getting both the front flap and the back of the folder to rise at the same time).

Here's a jsfiddle of what I have so far. Here to learn! Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/m4ax81r6/

Edit:
To add a little more clarification - the front and back of the folder need to rise together on hover of the front of the folder. Then the front of the folder needs to fold down, while all still risen. Last, the folder needs to fold back up and lower when the mouse stops hovering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        .folder {
            width: 500px;
            height: 250px;
            display: block;
            transition: transform .5s;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            position: relative
        }
        #folder1 {
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #folder2 {
            margin-top: -100px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #folder3 {
            margin-top: -100px;
            z-index: 3;
            bottom: 250px;
        }
        .movefolder:hover {
            transform: translatey(-100px);
        }
        .front {
            top: -105px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 240px;
            display: block;
            transition: transform .5s;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            position: relative;
            animation-delay: 2s;
            transform-origin: bottom;
            z-index: 4;
        }
        .openfolder:hover {
            transform: rotateX(-85deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin-left:50px;  margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:50px;">

    <img id="folder1" class="folder movefolder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/folder2-01.png" />
    <img id="folder2" class="folder movefolder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/folder2-01.png" />
    <img class="front openfolder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/front-folder-border-01.png" />
    <img id="folder3" class="folder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/folder2-01.png" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would have a div that is a container for both the folder and the front of it. It will make your movements way easier

Comment: Thanks. I thought that as well. I tried it before I posted here but things were acting really wonky. Let me re-make it and post a jsfiddle of that to show as well.

Comment: So here is when they are in a div and I move the div up. I get some shaky action depending on where your mouse hovers on the screen (specifically off to the right of the folder). https://jsfiddle.net/r2ry32r6/1/

Comment: I think I fixed it! I just didn't have a width to the div!
https://jsfiddle.net/4qfv2e5x/

Comment: Not quite fixed. Still have issues when adding multiple folders on top of that one... I'm getting folders flickering when trying to hover over them. It's like it is trying to do the animation for the folder behind it since it is lowered down behind it, but shouldn't the z-index be taking care of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try. I have added a base layer, and set different transition times on the base and hovered states.

It's important to make all hover changes on the same element, in this case the base element

```css
* {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#base1 {
  top: 200px;
}
#base2 {
  top: 400px;
}
.base {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: z-index 1s;
}

.base:hover {
  /*  z-index: 999;   probably not a good idea */   
}

.movefolder {
  transition: transform .5s .5s;
}
.base:hover .movefolder {
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: translatey(-105px);
}


.folder {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.openfolder {
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.base:hover .openfolder {
  transform: rotateX(-85deg);
  transition: transform .5s .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="base" id="base1">
<div class="movefolder" style="width: 500px;">
  <img class="openfolder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/front-folder-border-01.png" />
  <img class="folder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/folder2-01.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="base" id="base2">
<div class="movefolder" style="width: 500px;">
  <img class="openfolder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/front-folder-border-01.png" />
  <img class="folder" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8z-marketing/8z+Mortgage/folder2-01.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! I will mess around with this and see what I can make from it. Can you explain a little what you mean by "base?" Also, I see that during the animation, it "pops out of order." I'm assuming I can fix that with more z-indexes? I see that you have the same z-index for all folders and all open folders. If you have multiple like I'm thinking, is that what was causing my flickering? Again, thank you

Comment: Sorry about ny late answer, I haven't connected for 2 days. I set a div with class= base to keep something in the previous position and maintain the hover state if the moving element goes beyond the cursor position. I have commented the z-index change, probably it wasn't a good idea. And I believe that the flickering was because you set hover states on different elements. See how I have set all the hovers on base. Happy that it helped :-)